# Json. PHP. Get value by other value

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

I have this

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "id":463282624,
         "original_id":463282624,
         "defindex":10175,
         "level":1,
         "quality":4,
         "inventory":2147483980,
         "quantity":1,
         "attributes":[
            {
               "defindex":187,
               "value":1106771968,
               "float_value":31
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":465686099,
         "original_id":465686099,
         "defindex":10175,
         "level":1,
         "quality":4,
         "inventory":2147483979,
         "quantity":1,
         "attributes":[
            {
               "defindex":187,
               "value":1106771968,
               "float_value":31
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How can i take out the ['id'] of the item with ['defindex'] = 10175

Please help!

Comment: I have tried ['items'].['defindex']['10175']['id'] but it doesnt work

Comment: Probably need a loop and check if `defindex = 10175` then get the `id`

Comment: i have done that already... dont really like that. It takes so long to load

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't provide any way to retrieve elements by the contents, so you have to write a loop:

```
foreach ($object['items'] as $item) {
    if ($item['defindex'] == 10175) {
        $id = $item['id'];
        break;
    }
}
```

If you're going to need to do this repeatedly, you should transform your data into an associative array that uses `defindex` as the key, then you can access them easily.

```
$items_by_defindex = array();
foreach ($object['items'] as $item) {
    $items_by_defindex[$item['defindex']] = $item;
}

$id = $items_by_defindex[10175];
```

Comment: It looks like `defindex` number isn't unique as far as what the OP has posted. Also you have a extra `]`

Comment: The first solution only returns one of the IDs from duplicate `defindex`, so the second solution is no worse, except that the first code returns the first of the duplicates, while the second will return the last.